# DotNetNuke Unverified Users - Automatically Forward to A Particular Page After They Log In?

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke, registration, verification

Where do I write this code in DNN (version 7.x)? User has just logged in and is an unverified user.

- Check to see if they're in the Unverified Users role,
- And if they are, forward to a particular page.

**Situation Now:** When they're unverified, they can still navigate the site and see some stuff, and they'll see the "unverified user" message banners.

**What we need:** When an unverified user first logs in and when they try to navigate to any page (by typing URLs in their browser) once logged in, they should automatically get redirected to a particular page - one that has a text box to enter their verification number and/or a link/button to resend their verification.

Answer (score 0):

I've been asking for a feature like this for a while.  There should be an easy way to plug into DNN's login/logoff/authentication system.

1. What I did(for a similar situation) was I wrote a module that did not have anything to display, it just did stuff in the background using the Current User's information.  Then, there is a setting in DNN that say's "`Place this module on every page`".
   Your module could check the user's role, and redirect based on there role
2. There are also some free modules out there to do this: http://www.dnnsharp.com/dnn/modules/redirect